# Set radio button active based on boolean received from database in Angular Reactive Forms using mat-radio-button

Tags: angular, database, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on a reactive form in Angular 11. I've created two radio buttons which you cannot select both at the same time. From my database, I receive data about a user and fill my form with this data. If the property 'notification' is true, I want the first radio button to be checked, if this property is false, I want the second radio button to be checked.

**This is my html code:**

```
                <mat-radio-group formControlName="notification">
                    <mat-radio-button value="true">notification</mat-radio-button>
                    <mat-radio-button value="false">no notification</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
```

I use a method to display the user info in my form. It all works, including checking/unchecking checkboxes based on booleans received from my database. I can print out the booleans for my radio buttons too, so I know the values are available.

**This is (a part of) my component code:**

```
displayUserInfo(user: User): void {
    if (this.settingsForm) {
      this.settingsForm.reset();
    }
    this.settingsForm.setValue({
      email: user.DefaultMail,
      mobilePhone: user.DefaultMobilePhone,
      notification: user.Notification
    })
```

The first two values are filled in the form without any problem. But how do I use the true/false value of 'notification' to check or uncheck my radio buttons?

Extra: after managing this problem, I need to send this information back to a server when the user changed his info. How do I retreive the right boolean (one) for those two radio buttons?

Comment: Still,If you facing this issue please deploy into stackBlitz to help out more.

Comment: Because it seems no mistakes in your template and ts

Comment: I managed to make it work. You need to convert the booleans you receive from the back-end to strings to match them with their defined value in the html. In the opposite way, to send this information back to the back-end, you need to convert the string values to booleans. Radio buttons and check boxes clearly do behave differently.